# Godot - Raycast from camera to world

Tags: c#, raycasting, gdscript

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? I wrote this function in GDScript and then rewrote it in C#. It worked perfectly in GDScript but I seem to be getting an empty Dictionary in C#.

All I'm trying to do is cast a ray from the camera to the world.

GDScript:

```
func shootRay():
    var space_state = get_world().direct_space_state
    var mouse_position = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    rayOrigin = cam.project_ray_origin(mouse_position)
    rayEnd = rayOrigin + cam.project_ray_normal(mouse_position) * 2000
    var intersection = space_state.intersect_ray(rayOrigin, rayEnd)

    if not intersection.empty():
        return intersection
```

C#:

```
private Dictionary shootRay(){
    PhysicsDirectSpaceState spaceState = GetWorld().DirectSpaceState;
    Vector2 mouseScreenPos = GetViewport().GetMousePosition();
    _rayOrigin = _camera.ProjectRayOrigin(mouseScreenPos);
    _rayEnd = _rayOrigin + _camera.ProjectLocalRayNormal(mouseScreenPos) * 2000;
    Dictionary intersection = spaceState.IntersectRay(_rayOrigin, _rayEnd);

    return intersection;
}
```

Edit: It seems like when I hover only over a certain area of my viewport it does in fact detect a raycast, even if there is nothing in the world in that area. And even if I move the camera, the area it detects that object stays the same.

Edit: I had to change `ProjectLocalRayNormal` to `ProjectRayNormal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It worked perfectly in GDScript but I seem to be getting an empty Dictionary in C#

You can see that GDScript specifically checks for an empty `Dictionary`:

```
    if not intersection.empty():
        return intersection
```

GDScript would return `null` in the case of an empty `Dictionary` (The method in GDScript does not specify a return type, so it returns a Variant, which is `null` if no `return` statement is hit). Which is not true for the code in C#.

You can read on the documentation of [`intersect_ray`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html#class-physicsdirectspacestate-method-intersect-ray):

> If the ray did not intersect anything, then an empty dictionary is returned instead.

Which confirms that an empty `Dictionary` is expected.

---

**Addendum**: *Although I had not noticed at first, in the code in question translated `project_ray_normal` in GDScript to `ProjectLocalRayNormal` in C#. It should be `ProjectRayNormal`.*

Comment: Ok I understand, but in GDScript the Dictionary is never empty when I hover over my "Floor" node. But in C# it is always empty unless I hover over a certain part of my viewport, regardless of where the camera is positioned. (Even if there is no "Floor" in that area)

Comment: Would it make a difference if the script was attached to a different node instead of the camera node?

Comment: @Leonvb Your code has a reference to the `Camera`. So it does not need to be on it. By the way, you could get a reference to the `Camera` from the `Viewport` using [`get_camera`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_viewport.html#class-viewport-method-get-camera) (you are already getting the `Viewport` with `get_viewport`), that way you can make sure you are getting the correct `Camera`. - I suppose you changed something else on the scene that causes the problem. Also notice that without the check for empty `Dictionary` in the method, the code that calls it must handle it.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about being able to reference the camera from the viewport. I can't really think of anything that changed in my scene, but I will double check everything again. I will also add the empty check to my method. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: @Leonvb Since you say "over a certain part of my viewport"... Are you using multiple `Viewport`s? `get_viewport` will give you whichever `Viewport` is parent of the node where the script is attached. Which by default is the root of the scene tree (which is always a `Viewport`), so if you added a `Viewport` node you might be getting a different one depending where the script is attached - which might or might not be the one you want. **Addenum**: Check you placed the script in a node that is inside the `Viewport`  you want.

Comment: No I only have a single viewport (That I know of). But I'm a new to Godot so maybe I messed something up somewhere. Let me check.

Comment: Ah I got it. I had to change `_rayEnd = _rayOrigin + _camera.ProjectLocalRayNormal(mouseScreenPos) * 2000;` to `_rayEnd = _rayOrigin + _camera.ProjectRayNormal(mouseScreenPos) * 2000;`

Comment: @Leonvb I see, I skimmed the code and didn't notice that. You are welcome to post it as second answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change

`_rayEnd = _rayOrigin + _camera.ProjectLocalRayNormal(mouseScreenPos) * 2000;`

to

`_rayEnd = _rayOrigin + _camera.ProjectRayNormal(mouseScreenPos) * 2000;`